# Unable to Draw ZigZag Indicator on Chart using MQL5

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

I am trying to create a ZigZag indicator and draw it on the chart using MQL5. However, I'm facing difficulties in getting the indicator to appear on the chart. Here's my code

```
void TrendLineCreator::TrendLineCreatorDrawer()
  {

   double ZigZagBufferHigh[];
   double ZigZagBufferLow[];
   double ZigZagHandler = iCustom(_Symbol, _Period, "Examples/ZigZag");
   int ZigZagCountHigh = CopyBuffer(ZigZagHandler, 1, 0, 100, ZigZagBufferHigh);
   int ZigZagCountLow = CopyBuffer(ZigZagHandler, 2, 0, 100, ZigZagBufferLow);

   ArraySetAsSeries(ZigZagBufferLow,true);

   string trendlineName ="ZigZag_";
   datetime time1;
   datetime time2;

   for(int i = 1; i < ArraySize(ZigZagBufferLow)-2 ; i++)
     {
      if(ZigZagBufferLow[i] != ZigZagBufferLow[i+1])
        {
         if(iLow(_Symbol,_Period,i)!=ZigZagBufferLow[i])
           {
            time1 = iTime(_Symbol, _Period, i);
            time2 = iTime(_Symbol, _Period, i+1);
            trendlineName = "ZigZag_" + IntegerToString(i);
            ObjectCreate(0, trendlineName, OBJ_TREND, 0, time1, ZigZagBufferLow[i], time2, ZigZagBufferLow[i+1]);
            ObjectSetInteger(0, trendlineName, OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID);
            ObjectSetInteger(0, trendlineName, OBJPROP_WIDTH, 3);
            ObjectSetInteger(0, trendlineName, OBJPROP_COLOR, clrRed);
           }
        }
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome.

I would check the `ZigZagBufferLow[i]` by adding a line to print out its content:

```
   for(int i = 1; i < ArraySize(ZigZagBufferLow)-2 ; i++)
     Print("ZigZagBufferLow[i]: ",ZigZagBufferLow[i]);
     {
      if(ZigZagBufferLow[i] != ZigZagBufferLow[i+1])
      {...
```

You could print the other element `ZigZagBufferLow[i+1]` as well.

Hope this helps.